# What happens if I take a doubly-free simplicial abelian group?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Suppose that I have a simplicial set $X_\bullet$.  I can take the free abelian group generated by $X_\bullet$, $\mathbb{Z}X_\bullet$.  But then I can forget that this has an abelian group structure, and do it again to get $\mathbb{Z}U\mathbb{Z}X_\bullet$.  There is a natural map $\mathbb{Z} U \mathbb{Z} X_\bullet \to \mathbb{Z} X_\bullet$, and this map is a fibration of simplicial abelian groups.  Is this an acyclic fibration?

Comment: It is not. If you take a k-dimensional simplicial sphere $S$, then $\Bbb Z S$ is $K(\Bbb Z, k)$; $\Bbb Z (\Bbb Z S)$ computes homology of Eilenberg-MacLane space, and we know well that it's very much nontrivial.

Comment: It also fails when $X$ is discrete.